# Why am I getting # in urls when going back or refreshing while using react-router + ruby on rails + fluxxor

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, react-router

My friend and I have been stuck on this for days.

We've changed our ReactRouter.run to include ReactRouter.HistoryLocation (changed from using the default HashLocation) but we're still seeing '#'s appear in our urls when we go back to the previous page or refresh the page which gets us the 404 errors.

The Documentation says that we have to configure the server to "route all requests to the index template rendered by your server and then React Router will take over from there" but we're new to web development and am not sure how to achieve this, and do not know whether this is why we are having problems.

If the two problems are separate, I'd appreciate any comment or help on either(preferably both) problems.

Thanks!

P.S. We're using the most up-to-date versions of react, react-router, fluxxor, ruby, and rails

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer to your question:

To

> configure the server to 'route all requests to the index template
>   rendered by your server...'

you should use the following in your config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'application#index'
  get "/*path" => "application#index"
end
```

https://github.com/mariopeixoto/react-router-rails/tree/master/examples/react-router-example